# How to access a nested dict without knowing sub-dicts names

Tags: python, dictionary

I am parsing a lot of files, where data is stored in a nested dictionary. Sub-dicts' names may vary from file to file. Also, I think I might need to account for different length of their nesting. I always know the name of the dict I need to access, though. Say, I have dicts:

```
d = {'Unknown2': {'Unkw1': {'INeedYou': {'k': 'v'}}}}
d2 = {'anotherkey': {'INeedYou': {'k': 'v'}}}}
```

I always need to dig down to `{'k': 'v'}`. Can you think of any other way to access it except for `d['Unknown2']['Unkw1']['INeedYou']` syntax ?

I think I can use `d.keys()` to get the names and access the dict of interest with the method shown above, but since the nesting may be deep, it would take quite a few repetitions to access the dictionary I need.

I thought some of you may know some neat trick to get the job done more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you can avoid walking through the whole dictionary-tree until you find the key you find. The basic idea is:

```
def findDict (d, keyName):
    if not isinstance (d, dict): return None
    if keyName in d: return d [keyName]
    for subdict in d.values ():
        r = findDict (subdict, keyName)
        if r: return r
```

Comment: Glad to help. Just bear in mind that this approach is recursive and if you have more nested levels than maximum recursion depth (generally 500), this function will fail utterly and horribly. If your dicts have indeed more than 500 nested levels, you will need to derecursify (serialize) the function.

Comment: 500 is plenty in this case.